# Can I make a locked iTunes 'house account' for a library?

Tags: itunes, ipad, password, guest-account

I manage the computers at a public library.  We just got a donation of two iPad 2's.  I'd like to be able to lend the library patrons the iPad with the iTunes account setup (without a credit card) just for free apps/songs.

Is it possible to create an iTunes account with a “user” password that allows free apps and songs but restricts the user from changing the profile unless they have the “master” password?

Comment: FYI, I did a little looking on this and couldn't find anything. Even if you create an account with no credit card it'll still prompt for a username and password when downloading a free app. Someone could use the username and password to fiddle with the account later. Apple uses special "house accounts" in their stores that do exactly what you're looking for, but I don't know how to emulate that.

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell: No, this is not possible without custom modifications, like with the display models in Apple Stores. It'd be better to set up the apps and content you desire, and then lock out the functions through the parental controls to prohibit any foul play. The last thing you need is legal issues, which validly could happen. App Store apps can be downloaded after purchase by simply authenticating on a separate device. Music and other entertainment forms cannot, and hence will be stuck on the iPad if a customer decides to buy them on the iPad, leaving you guys on the hook for any transaction problems that might occur.

Tread carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Should anyone be looking for this post iOS 6, there are many solutions to manage iOS apps in the manner asked. You can start with Apple's MDM on Server.app which costs $20 on top of the cost of a used Mac that can run Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3819

Users will still be required to enter a username and password to get free apps.

Of course, you could always Jailbreak them ...